# How can I log in as myself

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid

With most browsers, logging in as myself (this account, that is) is not a problem. One browser though, insists on logging me in as user30485678. What can I do about that?

I tried clearing cookies, logging in through StackOverflow or through the openid.stackexchange.com URL, but I can't get into the Mr Lister account. When I do "log out" and then "log in" again, I sometimes can get to the login screen, but sometimes it bypasses the login screen altogether and logs me in as user200474 automatically.
If I do get the login screen, the large "log in with SO" button logs me in automatically (as the user987654 one), but when I click "more login options" and "log in with AOL" I get an error saying "Unable to log in with your OpenID provider. Canceled."

That's about it. Not sure what else I can try.

Edit: see answer.

Comment: Which browser would that be?

Comment: Firefox. On Linux.

Comment: Oh boy. I just found I could log in by sending a "forgotten password" email. Well, that wasn't very obvious.

Comment: Is this [meta-tag:status-completed], then?

Comment: Yes. However, as a normal user I cannot assign tags like those to my own posts.

Comment: @Emrakul Aside from what Mr Lister said (the red tags are moderator-only), they only get applied to bug reports (tagged [meta-tag:bug]), not support requests.

Comment: @CodyGray Ah, right. Forgot about that, sorry.

Comment: You should _never_ delete a question when you get an answer. If you figure out the problem, post it as an answer and mark it as accepted. Hey, you'll probably get a [nice badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) for it also :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that when I selected "recover your account" and had the system send a forgotten password email to my address, the system did recognise me for who I was.
Even if the email address I used was the same as the address I already was logged in with.
That is, the page https://openid.stackexchange.com now shows the same email address as when I was user2005026.

I don't know if what I encountered was a fluke, or if it's supposed to work this way, but it works now.